# Scheduled task as chrome extension

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

Can I make a scheduled to be as part of chrome extension ? I would like to write the task in JavaScript and make it run periodically in the browser while the browser is running.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out Chrome.alarms:

> Use the chrome.alarms API to schedule code to run periodically or at a specified time in the future.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/

Comment: Updated url : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms